# Has anyone used RNN package in R for Recursive Neural Network? How do I use that for prediction?

Tags: r, recurrent-neural-network

`rnn()` function R has no return statement. It generates synapses for input, hidden and output layer. How to use these for prediction with a test sample of a time series data?

Answer (score 1):

There was just an update of the `rnn` package, with the version 0.5.0, it can generalize outside of the toy example of binary addition.

You must use the `trainr` function to train the model and the `predictr` to predict the values on your data.

So far it only support synchronized many to many learning, understand that each new time point input will produce an output.